# Why SQL inner join is called as Inner and Outer Join called as Outer?

Tags: sql-server

Why SQL Join named as inner and outer?
what is the reason behind this?

this question was asked to me in an interview...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211638/why-is-inner-join-and-outer-join-so-called

Comment: Think Venn Diagrams and set theory. There's a fairly [decent explanation here](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join), and a quick search brought up lots more

Answer (score 2):

There are several explanations online, here is one. Inner is what matches both left and right side (inside both). Left/right mathces only that part:

[image: JOIN types described]

Answer (score 1):

When two tables are laid over top of each other on information that intersects, 
returning only the information “inside” the intersection is the INNER and returning all of the information 
is the OUTER.[image]